# Copy oracle specific columns of a table in .net collection like a List

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, csv

I am developping an asp.net application. An user can upload a csv files where each line is composed of 3 fields name,surname,age. I also have a oracle database where I have a table composed of name,surname,age,country. At each line of the csv, I have to check in my table if the name, the surname are registered in my table. So it's very costly in terms of performance. As my table is only updated nightly, I was thinking of copying name,surname of my oracle table in .net collection like a List. so I will have at each csv line to check if the fields are in my list and not to have to do an sql request where I will do a select count. So I have 2 questions :
Is this solution of copying my table in .net collection seems good?
If yes, can you explain me how to copy the content of an oracle table in .net collection?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think the most efficient way to do this would be to create a generalized model class to store each user. Like this...

```
public class User
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }

    // This comparer will be used to find records that exist or don't exist.
    public class KeyFieldComparer : IEqualityComparer<User>
    {
        public bool Equals(User u1, User u2)
        {
            return u1.Name == u2.Name && u1.Surname == u2.Surname;
        }

        public int GetHashCode(User u)
        {
            return u.Name.GetHashCode() ^ u.Surname.GetHashCode();
        }
    }
}
```

Now load both the CSV file and Oracle table into `List<User>` objects...

```
List<User> csvList;
List<User> oracleList;
```

When both lists are populated with data, it will be easy to see what already exists in each rather than hitting the database...

```
// This will filter users that are in the CSV file that don't already exist in oracle.
var newUsers = csvList.Except(oracleList, new User.KeyFieldComparer());
```

You can then loop through each new user and insert them...

```
foreach (var newUser in newUsers)
    InsertNewUser(newUser);
```

Hope this is helpful.

---

**UPDATE:**
My favorite way to load data from database to a list is using a micro-ORM such as Insight.Database. Simply search for Insight.Database in nuget and install the one that says Insight.Database.Providers.Oracle. You can then query the table into memory like this...

```
List<User> oracleList;
using (var db = new OracleConnection(ConnectionString))
{
    oracleList = db.QuerySql<User>("SELECT Name, Surname, Age, Country FROM Users");
}
```

As long as the properties in your class model match the name of the columns you're selecting, it will map them correctly (it's not case sensitive).

Comment: ok thanks, I have juste some questions for one part which is still not clear. How can I proceed to populate oraclelist with columns name and surname of my user table in my database, the most efficience and less costly in terms of performance way.

Comment: I am getting this erros when I try to use the Query method : 'Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection' does not contain a definition for 'Query' and no extension method 'Query' accepting a first argument of type 'Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Right click the project in the solution explorer. Click manage nuget packages. Make sure that Online -> nuget.org is select on the left side. Type "insight.database" into the search. Select Insight.Database.Providers.Oracle in the search results and click Install. This should add the necessary extension methods. Reference: https://github.com/jonwagner/Insight.Database/wiki/A-Quick-Tour

Answer (score 0):

Tre truth is that your best bet is to leave all of this to Oracle. So ..

First

1. Create a temporary table in your DB with the structure of (name, surname, age).

Then

1. Load your CSV to the temporary table.
2. Select data from your temporary table *antijoined* against your target table.
3. Load the rest (which would be CSV rows not present in your target DB table) into your target DB table.

There, all done. Honestly, there is no way you possibly could do this faster on the .NET side than in the Oracle.

**Steps 2+3** would be:

```
insert into target_table (name, surname, age)
select X.name, X.surname, X.age
from temporary_table X
where not exists (
        select 1
        from target_table Y
        where Y.name = X.name
            and Y.surname = X.surname
    );
```

As for **step 1**: Use arrays binding in C# for sending the data to Oracle in batches or just forget about C# and use the Oracle SQL*Loader or external tables for the fastest possible way.